# Where do all the numbers come from in the standard 2.2 gamma correction for RGB?

Tags: math, colors, formula, gamma

Here is the standard fwd Gamma 2.22 (1 / 0.45) correction formula:

```
for R,G,B < 0.018
R´ = 4.5 * R
G´ = 4.5 * G
B´ = 4.5 * B
for R,G,B ≥ 0.018
R´ = 1.099 * R^0.45 - 0.099
G´ = 1.099 * G^0.45 - 0.099
B´ = 1.099 * B^0.45 - 0.099
```

Where do the figures 0.18, 4.5, 1.099, and 0.099 come from? I specifically need to know how they are derived.

I need to know because I am writing a gamma correction function, and the simple approach of using a power and scaling, rather than the above, yields different results.

Comment: You will probably want to have a look at [the Gamma FAQ](http://www.poynton.com/GammaFAQ.html). It's a great read.

Comment: Those are the *encoding* formulas (sensor signal -> bytes), are you sure this is the *correction* you need?

Comment: @Stéphane this formula is a direct copy from Intel IPP. The correction is correct. I just want to know how the figures are derived.

Answer (score 1):

So here is how far I figured it.

The gamma correction function had to be designed with the following requirements (see [this paper](http://www.poynton.com/PDFs/SMPTE93_Gamma.pdf)):

- the voltage for 0 intensity must be 0
- the voltage for 1 intensity must be 1
- it must behave like a power function (exponent 1/2.22=0.45) close to intensity 1
- it must be linear close to the origin (to reduce the effect of sensor noise at low intensity)
- it must be continuous and continuously differentiable in [0,1]

so this problem can be solved by finding the numbers {a,b,c,x0} defining a function g:x->g(x) such as:

- g(x) = a*x^.45+b in [x0,1]
- g(x) = cx im [0,x0[
- g(1) = 1
- g(0) = 0
- lim{x->x0-}(g) = lim{x->x0+}(g)
- lim{x->x0-}(dg/dx) = lim{x->x0+}(dg/dx)

which yields the following equations:

- a+b=1
- c*x0=a*x0^.45+b
- c=0.45*a*x0^-0.55

equivalent to:

- a=1/(1-.55*x0^.45)
- b=-.55*x0^.45/(1-.55*x0^.45)
- c=.45*x0^-.55/(1-.55*x0^.45)

if you set x0 to 0.018, you get :

- a=1.099
- b=-.099
- c=4.5

The remaining questions is: how did they choose x0? I could not find any justification for the 0.018 value... Or they could have started with any of the other 3 parameters (for instance, set the toe slope to 4.5, they derive a,b and x0).

Not sure this will solve your problem, anyway I hope this helps (I had fun with the math).

Comment: Thanks @Stépahne. That is certainly a great start.

Comment: If you apply both formulas to the input, 0.018 is the approximate input value where both formula yield the same result. This is to be expected. Now, how to easily find this crossover point?

Comment: 0.02 is closer. Finding the crossover should work because the toe obviously ends at the crossover. This leads, then, to the question: why didn't they use 0.02, but instead used 0.018?